# Android Build Ends With 704 Errors But App Works

Tags: android

I have got an awkward problem on my Android App. When i build my app on Android Studio, build ends with 704 errors but app works on my test device correctly. I can't figured out the problem. I searched on Google and found some answers in stackoverflow but they did not help me. Because i don't use proguard right know on my project and the answers are all about proguard.

[image: here is my error logs:]

And below codes are my app level gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/piasy/maven"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'crashlyticsEnabled', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'logEnabled', 'true'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'crashlyticsEnabled', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'logEnabled', 'false'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile project(':chatlibrary')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.14'
    compile 'com.norbsoft.typefacehelper:library:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.piasy:rxscreenshotdetector:1.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.GDG-Korea:PinterestLikeAdapterView:29697e2c24'

}
```

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: These are the warnings or errors in the library included in your app

Comment: I can only see warnings in your screenshot, no errors.